# Why is the RTEMS Real-Time Operating System often used in European space industry?

Tags: software, esa

I was wondering recently about [RTEMS](https://devel.rtems.org/wiki/History/Timeline). Why is this Real-Time Operating System (RTOS) widely use in the European space industry among other suitable alternatives like freeRTOS or VxWorks?

Is this RTOS certified like SafeRTOS for instance?

Comment: [This is (a part) of what "Qualification" means. We have done this for RTEMS, and continue to do so as the Operating System evolves and accumulates more and more functionality](https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Space_Engineering_Technology/Software_Systems_Engineering/RTEMS)

Comment: I suspect support of the LEON processor may be a factor.

Comment: Indeed, according to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems), VxWorks only supports "ARM, IA-32, Intel 64, MIPS, PowerPC, SH-4, StrongARM, xScale", whereas RTEMS supports "ARM, Blackfin, ColdFire, TI C3x/C4x, H8/300, x86, 68k, Milkymist SoC, MIPS, Nios II, PowerPC, SuperH, SPARC, ERC32, LEON, Mongoose-V". Also, RTEMS is open source, making it much easier to verify and customize.

I sadly can't find an actual answer to your question, but that might be a good starting point.

Comment: Having first hand knowledge with the LEON processor, VxWorks supports SPARC based processors such as the LEON.